# Im trying to use some JSON data with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
    function setup() {
  loadJSON("https://api.pandascore.co/lol/champions.json?token=<token>", gotData);
}
function gotData(data) {
    var x = data.i.teams.name
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (x == "Neon Esports") {
            document.write(data.i.name);
        }
            document.write(data.i.teams.name);
    }
}
```

**but i am just getting this error** *Cannot read property 'teams' of undefined*

Comment: give us the structure of the fetched JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function gotData(data) {
     data = JSON.parse(data); // let JS know you're dealing with JSON
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var x = data[i].teams[0].name; // we get the name while fetching the data
        if (x == "Neon Esports") {
            document.write(x);
        }       
        document.write(data[i].teams[0].name);
     }
}
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: Thanks but i think i doesnt need the .parse(and its giving me an error) because i can write get data the name without it but i cant get any deeper than that.

Comment: tell me what's that error ?  "because i can write get data the name without it but i cant get any deeper than that." i didn't understand, sorry, could please explain more.

Comment: i meant deeper beacuse the data is nested thats why

Comment: as long as you know whats inside and how manu levels just loop through !

Comment: I want to get the data from this but it doesnt work "data[i].teams.name" the error says "name is not defined"